# soTimeout starts ticking from the moment you call it?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, connection, timeout

Is this right? or am I doing something wrong here ?

Set the timeout as so,

```
client.setSoTimeout(1000);    // timeout after READ_SlEEP if the socket is idle

Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Read from the socket

```
public String receive(){
        inStream = telnetCreator.getInputStream(client);
        int buff;
        String MessageReceived ="";
        try{
                if (inStream.available() > 0){
                    buff = inStream.read();
                    MessageReceived += (char) buff;
                    System.out.println(MessageReceived);
                }
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("MessageReceived :- "+ MessageReceived);
            return MessageReceived;
        }
        return MessageReceived;
    }
```

Since I'm setting the timeout as 1000 milliseconds and then sleeping for 2000 milliseconds, The socket throws an exception because the timer on read has already timed out.
This is pretty irritating. So now I have to set the timeout right before I use receive and then clear the timeout after every receive ?

Answer (score 0):

> `soTimeout` starts ticking from the moment you call it?

No. It starts ticking from the moment you execute a read.

> Since I'm setting the timeout as 1000 milliseconds and then sleeping for 2000 milliseconds

Why? Complete waste of time, literally.

> The socket throws an exception because the timer on read has already timed out.

No, it throws an exception because no data was received during the one-second  timeout from the moment you called `read()`.

> This is pretty irritating.

This is pretty stupid code. Remove the sleep and lengthen the timeout to something realistic. One second is an order of magnitude too small for a read timeoutl

> So now I have to set the timeout right before I use receive

No.

> and then clear the timeout after every receive?

No.

Comment: 1. I don't want to wait for more than 1 second.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a telnet server. I want to send a message and then wait 1 sec for a response. So king of a request response thing with the server. I have to do this multiple times. But if I have a sleep between two request-response, then it says read timeout